# Kubernetes : No difference in performances between 1 Pod and 3 Pods?

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, locust

I have a very simple Kubernetes Cluster that uses GKE (Google Cloud Platform) with 1 node (4 vCPU / 16 Go RAM)

This morning I was load testing an API (written in Python) on this cluster with [Locust](https://locust.io/). I only have one endpoint on my API, so I prepared a locust file to run differents configurations on that endpoint (with random parameters etc).

I first ran my Locust test with 10 users, 1 user generated every seconds (until limit reached), and the request wait time is between 1 and 2.5 seconds. I tested it first on just 1 pod and then I ran the exact same test on 3 pods. I noticed almost no improvement with 3 pods and the response times were just more spreaded.

**Here are the results for 1 Pod** :
[image: results 1 pod]
And the charts:
[image: charts 1 pod]

**And here are the results for 3 Pods**
[image: results 3 pods]
And the charts:
[image: charts 3 pods]

I am fairly new to K8s and I don't really understand everything, but my initial though was that increasing the number of running pods should improve the preformance right ? I should be able to handle 3 times more requests in the same time, but the results are far from that excepted conclusion.

And here is the yaml file defining the deployment on the K8s cluster (note: I set myself the replicas to 1 or 3 because for some reasons the autoscaler don't work) :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app_name
  name: app_name
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 3 or 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app_name
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app_name
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: >-
            gcr.io/path_to_image
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: app_name-v2-sha256-1
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app_name
  name: app_name-hpa-cbrt
  namespace: default
spec:
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
    - resource:
        name: cpu
        targetAverageUtilization: 80
      type: Resource
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: app_name
```

Additional info : The API calls a MySQL database and perform a request that get approx. 70k rows and do some stuff on those results. It only returns a json with few rows at the end.

Thanks in advance for any help you could provide !

Edit : Here is the definition of the load balancer, it's GCP generated and untouched

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
  creationTimestamp: "2021-05-11T10:03:16Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app: app_name
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: gcp-cloud-build-deploy
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app_name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: b8a19c9rth54erthe4rth8459633451fe8e73e038
  name: app_service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "87954231"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/app_service
  uid: service_uid
spec:
  clusterIP: 661.661.661.661
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30129
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: app_name
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 666.666.666.666
```

Comment: Seems to me that 36 seconds on average is very high. Adding more pods does not magically improve the performance. It however can take more load/requests at the same time. Depending if your backing hardware and database can handle that (like max connections, etc.) You also have to keep table locking, row locking etc in mind when using database queries. 
If you ask me, the way you are handling your queries can be improved much much better. Because fetching 70k records, and just returning a few rows means a lot of memory is used in your application, which probably causes your slow responses.

Comment: Are you using k8s Service for load balancing? Can you gather the statistics how your load was actually distributed? I. e. how many transactions / requests were handled by each pod?

Comment: @Leroy When there is no activity on the API, the usual response time is approx. 3 seconds. But as soon as I start testing, it goes rocket high.

Comment: @OlesyaBolobova I'm using GKE load balancer, I don't really know where I could find those infos using the GCP UI, do you know ?

Comment: @Pedro I added the definition at the end of the post. I see some metrics on GKE ingress&services and worloads but except few cpu and memory charts there is no real usefull info on there :/

Comment: Have you tried setting the replicas to "3" instead of "3 or 1" and see what happen?

Comment: @Pedro My bad, it was unclear, I just write it like this for the SO post :) In the file it's actually "3" !

Comment: Without seeing your Python code, it will be hard to figure out what's going on.  Given that with a single instance of your app the response time significantly increases under load, there is a bottleneck somewhere in  your app or perhaps even with the MySQL database.  I'd focus there before trying to scale horizontally.